# Is ToroDB available for aws DocumentDB

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

Hi I'd like to move some data from an AWS DocumentDB to a PostgreSQL, I've found on the web ToroDB that would be the best tool for my task. It's implemented for MongoDB I'd like to know if I can use it also in AWS DocumentDB (with MongoDB compatibility)
Thank you in advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see in ToroDB [documentation](https://www.torodb.com/stampede/docs/1.0.0/about/) , is using the oplog to tail the changes in MongoDB, not change streams. Amazon DocumentDB doesn't have the oplog collection, but does supports change streams. Unless ToroDB gets updated to support change streams (which I doubt it will, documentation says only MongoDB 3.2 and 3.4 are supported and last Github update is from 5 years ago), is not going to be able to live replicate from DocumentDB.

However, if the destination is AWS RDS PostgreSQL or AWS Aurora PostgreSQL, then [AWS DMS](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) can be used to replicate from DocumentDB.